# Basic Solr query & data structure

Tags: mysql, solr

I need to use Solr for a very quick demo, I have a MySql database that contains 37k records of products online (like gmail, google analytic) where I have information like name, description, and keywords.

I managed to store the data like this structure

```
{        
    "keywords":"[\"music-streaming,streaming,internet-radio,audio-scrobbling\"]",
    "description":"Last.fm is a music community website that offers personalized internet radio, using a recommendation system called \"Audioscrobbler\" to build a detailed profile of users based on their music tastes and interests. The service...",
    "operatingSystem":"[\"Mac,Windows,Linux,Web/Cloud,Android,iPhone,WindowsPhone,KindleFire\"]",
    "meta":"[\"Freemium\", \"Mac\", \"Windows\", \"Linux\", \"Web/Cloud\", \"Android\", \"iPhone\", \"...\", \"WindowsPhone\", \"KindleFire\"]",
    "name":"Last.fm",
    "id":39145,
    "category":"audio-and-music"}
```

Meta & operating system are JSON arrays, while the remaining fields are text fields.

I need help in three things

1. Is this data structure (schema) is good in terms of structure, searching, and indexing?
2. I want to build a query where is shows relevant products based on keywords?
3. How can I turn the fields meta and operating system into filters rather than search keywords?

My final goal is to have a search bar where a user can type in a specific keyword then filter according to operating system and meta

Answer (score 0):

The fields with multiple values should probably be indexed as separate terms in a multiValued field, so that you can query / filter for fields with a specific value. i.e. index the field as 'Mac', 'Windows', 'Linux', 'Web/Cloud', etc., and not as a single value with all the values embedded.

Depending on your exact requirements, similar / relevant documents can be found using the [MoreLikeThis](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/MoreLikeThis) component.

When the fields are properly multivalued (as they should be) you can [generate a Facet on the field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting) for filtering (and then use `fq` to filter the result set accordingly).

Comment: Thanks, business logic wise this is what I am looking for, technically I need to learn how to implement what you mentioned. Thanks for the tips

Comment: You can use the `dataimporthandler`  to load data from MySql. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler